# Customising MapInfoWindow (xamarin.forms.maps) and add second label if it's possible using android - xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: I want to remove this elements from info window]

I'm new to using `xamarin.forms.maps` and want to remove the Logo, this monkey from the left side and this icon(i) from the right side.

Also I want to add a second label if it's possible ?

With this code I call the pin and set the coordinates and other stuff:

```
CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(41.56488683065354, 26.13941661843389),
            Label = "р. Чорбаджийска",
            Name = "Xamarin",
            Address = "с. Островец",
        };
```

I have 17 pins and want to add a variable on the second Label under `Address`.

What can I do add second label.

My objects from the Pin are:

```
 using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace CustomRenderer
{
    public class CustomPin : Pin
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int CodeNum { get; set; }
        public int AlertLevel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to set `AlertLevel` like a second label under the `address`.

How can I remove this three images on the info window ?

My CustomRenderer look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using CustomRenderer;
using CustomRenderer.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            base.OnMapReady(map);

            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.green));
            return marker;
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
            {
                var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
            if (inflater != null)
            {
                Android.Views.View view;

                var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
                if (customPin == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
                }

                if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
                }

                var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
                var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);

                if (infoTitle != null)
                {
                    infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
                }

                return view;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {
            var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: modify the XamarinMapInfoWindow layout to suit your needs.  Then in GetInfoContents () set the properties of your modified layout.

Comment: Can you give me some docs or example how to modify XamarinMapInfoWindow ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/

Comment: How can I remove the icons ?

Comment: How do you remove something with any editor?  Select it and hit delete.  Or read the docs that I linked to which explain in detail how to use the editor.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/designer-basics?tabs=windows#context-menu-commands

Comment: I not use editor, how to delete the icons in the code ?

Comment: Are you even trying to figure this out yourself?  Delete the controls with "Image" in their name, like "ImageView" and "ImageButton".

Comment: Where did you copy this code from? What tutorial are you trying to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see the method `GetInfoContents`

```
if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
     {
           view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
     }
else
     {
           view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
     }
```

this is where you inflate the ui with `Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow` or `Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow`.

So you just need open the `XamarinMapInfoWindow.xml` and `MapInfoWindow.xml` inside `Resources/layout` folder ，delete the corresponding `ImageView` or `ImageButton` and you also could  add a second label inside it.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I remove all Images but I want to set public int CodeNum { get; set; } another one label here: marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
I create New  textView for second label with name= InfoWindowSubtitle2

Comment: Can you check my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768515/how-to-set-second-label-on-infowindow-xamarin-map

Comment: @RositsaV I have checked it and given you a suggestion,you could have a try.